# How to draw polygons using R based with the length and area based on some values?

Tags: r

Let's say I have four values and its average.

```
      data <- data.frame(a= c(10,5,2,3), b=c(15,8,9,10) c=(8.5,9,10,11),  d= c(11.1,5.5,6.7,9) avg = c(11.15, 15.6, 4, 8)
```

I want to draw something which looks like this:

[image: Example]

The area of the polygon should match the avg and the four sides should somehow correspond to the `a, b, c` and `d` values. Is it possible to do in R?

Comment: could probably use the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) in combination with some normalizations (e.g., first vertex at the origin, second vertex up along the y axis) and the distance formula as inputs to an equation solver. i'm not savvy enough with geometry to offer much better.

Comment: I want four polygons/

Comment: do you require convexity?

Comment: Yes, convexity, if present, would be great!